# Is there a way in Python to create a tuple of the components matched in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way in Python to create a tuple of the components matched in a regular expression?
For instance, this is what I am trying to do.

```
import re
pattern = '^[A-Z]{5} [0-9]{6}(C|P)[0-9]{1,3}$'
str = 'ABCDE 020816C110' 
m = re.match(pattern,str)
print m.group()
ABCDE 020816C110
```

I want to make something that looks like `('ABCDE','020816','C','110')` (*based upon the parts within the regex*)
and if my pattern is different, say,

```
pattern = ^[A-Z]{1,4} [A-Z]{2} [A-Z]$
str = 'ABC FH P'
```

I would eventually get **`('ABC','FH','P')`**
It seems I have to split on components of the regex that will be different by pattern.

I am considering making *n* number of separate calls to `re.search` with only the component pattern, but I doubt I will always find the appropriate substring or it will return more than I want.

Comment: use re.findall, it'll give you a list, you can convert it to a tuple pretty easy if it's needed

Comment: using `re.findall` isn't needed and doesn't make sense with a both side anchored pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *capturing groups*:

```
>>> pattern = '^([A-Z]{5}) ([0-9]{6})(C|P)([0-9]{1,3})$'
>>> m = re.match(pattern, str)
>>> m.groups()
('ABCDE', '020816', 'C', '110')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '^([A-Z]{5}) ([0-9]{6})(C|P)([0-9]{1,3})$'
>>> s =  'ABCDE 020816C110'
>>> m = re.match(pattern, s)
>>> m.groups()
('ABCDE', '020816', 'C', '110')
```

You can use groups, and `match`, for this you only have to add `(` and `)` in the correct places.